# Is there any profiler for laravel like codeigniter's?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, profiler

I was searching for a solution a couple hours but it seems like so far there isn't any non-outdated solution.

P.S. such a framework with huge fuss like laravel makes me surprise. that was a great disappointment...

Comment: [BlackFire](https://blackfire.io/) should work with almost any framework - http://www.thirdandgrove.com/profile-laravel-quickly-with-blackfire-io/

Comment: most of the results you found are out dated because codeigniter is outdated in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to try Laravel Debugbar: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar